# React/Graphql: Display query results

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-js

So after the user clicks the submit button I can see the result in the console.  Can someone give me some pointers, or example, using the code below, on how to display those results? I am honestly out of ideas.  Been on this for a week now.  All the examples I've seen have static data or loads data upon rendering.  My app executes a query upon clicking the submit button; no preloaded data.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          startTime: '',//This will keep track of the date/time
          endTime:''
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

      }

      handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state.startTime);
        this.setState({
          startTime: new Date(document.getElementById("startTime").value).valueOf(),//getElementById is a jQuery method
          endTime: new Date(document.getElementById("endTime").value).valueOf()
        }, () => {
          this.props.data.refetch({//Assign the inputvalues, which is the current state, to the variables after pressing the submit button
            startTime: this.state.startTime,
            endTime:this.state.endTime
          });
          console.log(this.state.startTime);
          console.log(this.state.endTime);
        });
      };

      render() {

        console.log(this.props);
        return (
          <div className="Calendar">
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
              <label>Start Time</label>
              <input type="datetime-local" id="startTime" step="1" />              



              <label>End Time</label>
              <input type="datetime-local" id="endTime" step="1" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>

          </div>

        );
      }
};
export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, 
  { options: (ownProps) => { 
    console.log(ownProps.startTime); 
    return ({ variables: { startTime: ownProps.startTime,
                            endTime: ownProps.endTime
     } }) 
  } } )(Calendar);
```

Comment: Since you are sing the `graphql` HoC. You should get the data from the query in `this.props.data.{your_entity_name}`. If the result of the query is an array you can use for example `.map` so you display the fields you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have half of what you need for the query, the props portion of the query will be able to assist you with returning the data back to your component.

```
export default graphql(getObjectsQuery, {
  options: (ownProps) => { 
    console.log(ownProps.startTime); 
    return ({ 
      variables: { 
        startTime: ownProps.startTime,
        endTime: ownProps.endTime
      }
    }) 
  },
  props({ data }) {
    // Data will contain loading, error, and your return object type
    // Since I am destructuring here, you'll need to use the property name
    // you've given in the query
    const { loading, error, returnData } = data;
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    return { loading, returnData };
  }
})(Calendar);
```

At this point your component will have props with the returned data after loading has finished. You can then `.map` over anything as needed for display.

Comment: You may not be using Apollo, but the concept is still the same, and here is their documentation on manual queries:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/queries.html#manual-query